# starting the android app at start of phone

Tags: android

I want my android activity to be displayed on start of the phone but the app is crashing, and I m unable to take the log as well. Here is the code
Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

        <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".StartupActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
           </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

BOOTUPRECEIVER.JAVA

```
package com.example.sample;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         Intent i = new Intent(context, StartupActivity.class); 
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i); 

     }
    }
```

STARTUPACTIVITY.JAVA

```
package com.example.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.android.R;

public class StartupActivity extends Activity {



     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     }
    }
```

Could some one help me with the issue

EDIT:
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android/com.android.StartupActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.StartupActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.android-1.apk]
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.StartupActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.android-1.apk]
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
03-20 16:05:24.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2709):     ... 11 more

Comment: I can see my app in manage applications to uninstall, but I dont see in the normal applications grid dsiplay

Comment: If you run StartupActivity by itself, does it crash?

Comment: I dont  have any logic in startupactivity..it just shows hello world. so I guess there is no problem with startupactivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android 3.0 and higher, an bootup reciever will not run until the activity has been launched at least once by hand.  So most likely you aren't ever running.

You aren't appearing in the grid because you have no launcher activity.  Add this to the activity tag in your manifest

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Then run the app once.  After that it ought to work.

Comment: I have made the changes, but now a new error , have updated the query

Comment: Your package name for the app is com.android.  This means your activity would need to be in com.android to use the .ClassName method of naming it, rather than a fully qualified package and class name.  I suggest changing your package to something unique, trying to place your stuff in com.android will lead to problems.

Comment: I changed it this way but no use
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

Comment: Changing that has changed your logcat. Update it again.